# Android, Eclipse & CM10.1 Profile Manager

Tags: android, eclipse, cyanogenmod

I want to switch cm profile manager profiles from within my app.

I found that i need to get the service from ProfileManager, so after digging in cm10 sources i figured

```
import android.app.IProfileManager;
import android.app.ProfileManager;
```

will do the deal, but how do i have to import this in eclipse?

Do I have to download and include full cm10 sources?

Comment: In the meanwhile i found that i need a classes.jar file from cm sources and import it in eclipse. When i find the time and manage to succesfully integrate profile manager to my app i will answer my own question.

Comment: Could you tell me what JARs did you have to include?

Comment: This is what a dev wrote me when i asked him how he id it, however i couldn't try it yet:

"you will need the 'classes.jar' file for CM. I don't know where is the best place to get it. I found it when I tried to build CM for the emulator (which didn't work for me). It was located in cm9_github/android/system/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/framework_intermediates/. I then unselected the jar from the SDK in eclipse and selected this one instead"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone is still trying to find a way to control CM Profiles:

CM introduced it's platform SDK, which allows you to do just that.
https://github.com/CyanogenMod/cm_platform_sdk/wiki

It's also on maven central

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.cyanogenmod:platform.sdk:4.+'
}
```